# Making an operation asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a big application that implements some services, the interface it uses is

```
IResult Execute(IRequest)
```

Its all wrapped inside an IHttpHandler. Some of these services use a common infrastructure component I want to replace. The problem is, my component takes long time to run, and since all this is hosted inside an IIS server it will very quickly exhaust its worker threads.

I can wrap the services inside an IHttpAsyncHandler, but I still need a way to use my component asynchronously, other wise I'll just be holding a different worker thread.

I of course can just execute my service inside it's own thread, but it's very expensive.
using System.Threading.Tasks.Task or Delegate.BeginInvoke, would just hold up another thread or worker thread, depending on implementation.

Ideally, I would like if I could, when my long running operation is called, take the thread's stack, and execution context, save them aside, start doing my work (which is mostly IO and asynchronous by itself), release the thread im using to the thread pool\ OS, and when done take the context I saved aside and continue execution with my result.

This is very possible in some functional languages or when using continuation, how can it be achieved in C#?

---

After doing some research, I think what I need to do, is a sort of continuation. I need to freeze my current execution thread stack, release the thread back to the pool, and restart the frozen stack, on the callback from the async operation I'll be using.

---

To Justin Pihony's request I'm adding some code to better describe my problem.

This is my Http Handler (a simplification of course):

```
class Handler: IHttpAsyncHandler 
{
        private readonly Action<HttpContext> _processDelegate = ProcessRequest;

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
           IBuissnessService blThing = IOC.Get(context.Something);

           // usually doesnt take too long...
           thing.DoWork(context);
        }


        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
        {
            return _processDelegate.BeginInvoke(context, cb, extraData);
        }

        public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            _processDelegate.EndInvoke(result);
        }
}

//this is the buissness object

    class BLThing :IBuissnessService 
    {
        public void DoWork(HttpContext)
        { 
        //.... a Lot of Stuff

        // in some point one of the objects this is using does:
        IDoWork someObject = IOC.GetSomthing();
        var result = someObject.DoWork();

        // uses the result some more
        // and eventually returns.
        }
    }

    class SomeObject : IDoWork 
    {
        public Result DoWork()
        {
         // does some very long http call to another server
        }
    }
```

I can't change "BLThing" but I fully control "SomeObject " also eventually i need to support the same interface "BLThing" expects.

I want to add to  "SomeObject" two async methods (BeginDoWork, EndDoWork) and write:

```
class SomeObjectWrapper : IDoWork 
{
    SomeObject _worker ;
    public Result DoWork()
    {
         worker = new SomeObject();
         ThreadState state = CurrentThread.CaptureState();
         worker.BeginDoWork(Callback,state)
         CurrentThread.PurgeStateAndReturnToPool();
    }

    void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
       var processingResult = worker.EndDoWork(result);
       ThreadState state  =(ThreadState) result.AsyncState;
       state.ReturnTopCall(processingResult);
       CurrentThread.RestoreThreadState(state);
    }
}
```

---

Well in .Net doing this is not possible. Actually it is, but would require a lot of work, and probably won't give any performance benefit over create a full blown thread. an approach like this will be beneficial only in a language (or platform) that is much more functional in nature, and has a memory and threading model rather different then the one Win-API is using.

Although if one initially writes his code in an asynchronous manner, or relies on the TPL, he could probably achieve this quite easily...

I'm awarding the bounty to Justin, if not for the answer then for the discussion.

Comment: Interesting, but i dont think there's a proper .NET API for that...

Comment: If there is a thread context, there is a thread.

Comment: Fiber support was removed from .NET 2.0 and user-mode scheduling can be achieved in .NET 4.0 using various PFX api.

Comment: @sixlettervariables didn't get your point.

Comment: PFX is the Parallel Extensions to .NET, in 4.0 this is PLINQ (parallel LINQ) and TPL (Task Parallel Library).

Comment: well it won't solve my problem... I'll need to rewrite a lot of the code to use the TPL... and i wan't to avoid exactly that...

Comment: If I am reading the code and your comments right, then it looks like the BLThing is going to sit and wait for someobject to return? So, the process ends up being synchronous anyway as the top layer is out of your control and will sit and wait anyway. If your http call does take a while, then wrapping your calls in the TPL (which should require less code than writing begin and end invokes), might result in the call running somewhat async while it waits for data. I would still lean towards this as your best option, and must repeat that it is usually not worth micromanaging the threadpool

Comment: @JustinPihony that is exactly what i want to avoid, the business object sitting around and waiting. And It's very doable with continuation, and fibers. Managing the thread pool is usually pointless, but not when handling so many requests...

Comment: @Hellfrost But, by the way that you wrote this, the BLThing makes a call to your SomeObject and then, in the same method, does something with the results. So, you have to add the continuation into the BLThing, and since you cannot change that code, it will continue to wait for the results no matter how you write your code. So, I am not sure that this is solvable the way you are asking...

Comment: @JustinPihony the thing is, in other programming languages it is, if i can post the rest of my function as continuation inside the worker object. Or using Fibers...
the more im reading about this im coming to the conclusion it isn't feasible too...

Comment: @Hellfrost Well, good luck. Even if you were to use the 5.0 features of await and async, you would still block as soon as it tries to use the results...I am not sure how other languages get around code you dont have control over trying to use uninstantiated results without throwing errors or blocking...

Comment: @JustinPihony It's something trivial in some functional languages.

Comment: @Hellfrost Ahh, I think the keyword there is functional :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you not using the Task library? You dont need to micromanage the threadpool in this case. If the Task is truly async and waiting, then the thread will be used by something else until the async method gets the value it is waiting for?

Try using Tasks and their ContinueWith functionality

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(code);
Task taskForSynchronous = t.ContinueWith(
    (previousTask)=>{synchronous code after t is done},
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
);
newTask.ContinueWith(
    (previousTask)=>{more asynchronous code}
);
```

If you actually watch the usage, you will notice the threadpool manages this quite efficiently.

Comment: Please read my question again... The TPL won't help me, I have a lot of synchrounus code between my Http-Handler and my component and I want to avoid using up a thread if I dont need it...

Comment: I just edited my code to address that. You will notice the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), which should deal with any code that needs to be synchronous when the async returns. This way, it will spin up an appropriate thread, but then jump back onto the calling thread when the asynchronous action is complete. That is if I am understanding you properly. If the sync code that relies on the async data must wait for the async data, then this is still relatively the best solution I see...or else this really is a synchronous method from the start.

Comment: @kenny, That is a great clarification that async does not mean that a thread is actually being wasted. The threadpool is smart and will not waste time waiting on async. So, async != thread and there is a difference between async and parallel. Please keep that in mind when thinking of your threads. That might be where our misconception came from

Comment: What's this "using up" of full fat threads? I understand the worker pool might run from a limited number of threads, but you can spawn as many full fat one's as you like can't you?

Comment: If you spin up more threads than you have CPU's, then you have to start dealing with context switching, which is slower. So, the optimal situation is to have no more threads than you have processors. So, spinning up threads costs more after you reach that threshold

Comment: @JustinPihony , partialy true, there is no context switching for a mutexted thread. But every thread holds a lot of resources, and involves the kernel...

Comment: @Hellfrost There shouldn't be a lot of resources to a thread, the whole point was to have fewer than a process. These threads will on an IO wait by the sound of it, so are unlikely to cause thrashing. Why worry about the kernel though? You're basically looking at implementing your own context switch and it'll be slower than the kernel's.

Comment: @JonB Each thread, takes around 64K-100K of memory (stack, and local storage). When dealing with hundreds or thousands of requests per second, you can't spawn to many threads. I don't want to implement thread scheduling, I just want simple continuation, or co-routines.

Comment: @Hellfrost There's a way you can bodge it with "yield return", I guess you've seen this? http://www.replicator.org/node/80

Comment: @Hellfrost Now I am really confused? I presented you with a solution that is essentially a co-routine/simple continuation. This article (http://bit.ly/bshmbF) about the C# 5.0 await/async even has Eric Lippert referring to async methods as basically being coroutines. If you want to wait for your async code to return then you can just use the Task's Wait method? Could you possibly edit your question to have a sample idea of the code to provide more clarity? Maybe that will make it more evident of what you are looking for?

Comment: @JonB It's a sort useful only for very specific circumstances... i dont see how will it solve my problem...